# Layout.css is missing from a custom not found page

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I'm trying to add a custom 404 page inside my Next app.
I want to use the same 404 page for all my "not found" routes.
My app directory looks like the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a6Fm.png) While my [root layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxaWi.png).

If I navigate to a none existing route localhost:3000/example or a nested one localhost:3000/headphones/example, I'll be redirected to the not-found page.
It's working as expected But I noticed that the not found page is missing the layout.css file while the not-found.module.css is loaded normally.

The not found page component is quite simple.

```
import styles from '@/styles/pages/notFound.module.css'

import Link from 'next/link'

const NotFound = () => {
  return (
    <div id={styles.container_not_found}>
      <h1>not found</h1>
      <Link href='/'>go back home</Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NotFound
```

I observed the network tab in chrome when I do a page request.
If I request the home page or any existing page, I can clearly see the layout.css and the page's module CSS files are been requested. However, If I request a non existing route, only the not-found.module.css is requested. This means, The header and footer aren't styled in my not found page.

Comment: Experiencing the same behavior on Next.js 14.0.4 where the not found page is missing styling and not loading the layout.css page.  However, this doesn't occur when doing a production build, only when running the project in dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try including your layout CSS globally:

```
// _app.js (or _app.tsx)
import '../styles/layout.css'; // Include your layout.css globally

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: When I initially created my Next app the Layout.css file didn't exist. I didn't create the file either. It looks like Next is creating the file and filling it with all CSS related to the Root layout like those of my header and footer etc...

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/not-found.tsx`

```
import Link from 'next/link'
 
export default function NotFound() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Not Found</h2>
      <p>Could not find requested resource</p>
      <Link href="/">Return Home</Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

For using your `global.css` which is imported on `layout.tsx` you don't need to import again on your `not-found.tsx` page. You can directly access the classes like `className='yourCustomCSS'`

Make sure you have imported your `globals.css` file into the root `app/layout.tsx`

```
import './globals.css' // < THIS LINE

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Read more on CSS: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-modules

Read more on not found page: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found